# jquery - trying to use pattern matching with window.location.pathname

Tags: jquery, select, path, match

Basically, if I'm at: http://example.com/content/connect/152, I want to find out if "connect" is present in the url and then set the selected value of a menu to something specific...  (The url could also be something like http://example.com/content/connections, in which case, it should still match...)

This is what I've been trying, which, clearly isn't working....

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
if(path).match(/^connect) {
 $("#myselect").val('9');
} else {
 $("#myselect").val('0');
}
```

Comment: I think you simply have a typo in if. Shouldn't it be if(path.match(/^connect))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since connect can be anywhere in your URL there is no need to add the ^

try :

```
if (path.match("/connect"))
```

this assume that you want a "/" right before a connect

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will only match values beginning with connect.

You probably want this:

```
if(path.match(/^.*connect.*$/)) {
```

Comment: Again, the same typo as I've described in OP's comment. Should've been if(path.match(/^.*connect.*$/)) { ...

Comment: if(path.match(/^.*connect.*$/)) {